# c# unity IEnumerator not working in eventhandler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

ConnectToWebSocket() is working but when i try to fire tryConnectToWebSocket() that not working
when i run i am getting this log (ws://localhost:8080/user) when i turn off server i am getting these logs (you losted connection) and (false)
But i cant see  "this message from outside of while loop" and "this message from inside while loop" on console. So my IEnumerator tryConnectToWebSocket() not working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using WebSocketSharp;

public class websocks : MonoBehaviour
{

public static WebSocket ws = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/user");
public static bool stop;
public delegate void MyDelegate(string num);
public static MyDelegate myDelegate;

private void Awake()
{
    stop = false;
    StartCoroutine(ConnectToWebSocket());
    
}
private IEnumerator ConnectToWebSocket()
{
    ws.Connect();
    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) => myDelegate(e.Data);
    if (ws == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("coudn't connect");
        
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(ws.Url);
        
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
   
}


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    websocks.ws.OnClose += (sender, e) =>
    {

        Debug.Log("you losted connection");
        Debug.Log(ws.IsAlive);
        
        stop = true;
        StartCoroutine(tryConnectToWebSocket());

    };
   
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{


}

public IEnumerator tryConnectToWebSocket()
{
    Debug.Log("this message from outside of while loop");

    while (ws.IsAlive == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("this message from inside while loop");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        ws.Connect();
    }
    if (ws.IsAlive == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("connected");
        stop = false;
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Probably because tryconnect is not static and is only available to an instance of your class. You’d probably do better with a singleton and calling that

Comment: srry Coroutines can only be executed on objects that inherit from MonoBehaviour. I tested static Coroutines but not worked i think problem is eventhandler but i coudnt find any docs about it

Comment: this error occur "IsObjectMonoBehaviour can only be called from the main thread." when i use try catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is threading. Most of the Unity ApI may only be used by the Unity main thread.

The events `OnClose` and `OnMessage` etc are most probably called on a background thread.

You could use a main thread dispatcher pattern like e.g.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using WebSocketSharp;

public class websocks : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static WebSocket ws = new WebSocketSharp.WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/user");
    public static bool stop;
    public delegate void MyDelegate(string num);
    public static MyDelegate myDelegate;

    // Thread-safe Queue (first-in first-out)
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        stop = false; 
    }

    private void Start ()
    {
        // Enqueue to the actions so it will be executed in the main thread
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) => _actions.Enqueue(() => myDelegate(e.Data));

        websocks.ws.OnClose += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _actions.Enqueue(() => 
            {
                Debug.Log("you losted connection");
                Debug.Log(ws.IsAlive);
        
                stop = true;
                StartCoroutinee(tryConnectToWebSocket());
            });
        };

        StartCoroutine(ConnectToWebSocket())
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        // Work the actions off in the Unity main thread
        while(_actions.TryDequeue(out var action)
        {
            action?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ConnectToWebSocket()
    {
        if (ws == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("coudn't connect");  
            yield break;      
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log(ws.Url);          
        }

        ws.Connect();

        // Waiting at the end of a Coroutine has absolutely no effect 
        // This should probably be a normal method instead
        yield return null;      
    }

    public IEnumerator tryConnectToWebSocket()
    {
        Debug.Log("this message from outside of while loop");
    
        while (ws.IsAlive == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("this message from inside while loop");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
            ws.Connect();
        }
        if (ws.IsAlive == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("connected");
            stop = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is true thx. I have one more question. That is locking game i think it is using too much cpu or etc how i can prevent it because ws.connect() is easy for every 5 seconds