# I'm trying to convert the Dash feature from an old input system to the new input system Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm implementing a Dash feature in my 2D Game in Unity. I was using the "old" Input system and everything was working correctly!

```
///Old InputSystem
//DASH
if (dashing)
        {
            return;
        }

if (canDash)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            {
                
                if (Time.time - lastDashTime < timePresses)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(Dash());
                    
                }
                else if (!firstbuttonPressed)
                {
                    firstbuttonPressed = true;
                    lastDashTime = Time.time;
                }
                else
                {
                    firstbuttonPressed = false;
                    
                }
            }

        }
            }`

private IEnumerator DashAction()
{
float dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
canDash = false;
dashing = true;
float originalGravity = heroBody.gravityScale;
heroBody.gravityScale = 0f;
heroBody.velocity = new Vector2(dirX* dashDistance, 0f);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingTime);
heroBody.gravityScale = originalGravity;
dashing = false;
yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingCooldown);
canDash = true;

    }

}

//NEW InputSystem

public void Dash(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
if(context.performed)
{

             StartCoroutine(DashAction());
            Debug.Log("DUPLO CLIQUE");
        }
            
    }
    
    
    
    
    // Funcao para o DashAction
    
private IEnumerator DashAction()
    {
    
        float dirX = transform.position.x;
        canDash = false;
        dashing = true;
        float originalGravity = heroBody.gravityScale;
        heroBody.gravityScale = 0f;
        heroBody.velocity = new Vector2(dirX* dashDistance, 0f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingTime);
        heroBody.gravityScale = originalGravity;
        dashing = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingCooldown);
        canDash = true;
        
    
    }
```

But now I wanted to switch to the "new" Input Sytems, with event calling, and Dash doesn't work anymore! I debugged the code and my event is well configured in unity!

What's supposed to happen is that Dash works with the new input system!
I've debugged the DashAction function and the values of X are being printed correctly, it just doesn't do Dash

I've debugged the Dash event for the console and everything is correct and well configured, but the Dash still doesn't work!
When I double-click on A or D, it prints the message from debug.log

Comment: did you enable the actions? How did you link up the action?

Comment: I link up the action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a coroutine issue I believe. Events can't trigger coroutines as they must be triggered by the main thread. It worked with the old input system you had programmed because you were probably triggering the coroutine from update() or a method called by update.

[Unity Coroutine is not starting when called from an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71670335/unity-coroutine-is-not-starting-when-called-from-an-event-handler)

The solution in the link above is for the event to append the coroutine to a list. Then the next update executes everything in that list. This works because the update occurs on the main thread.