# My event isn't being enqueued to my action list inside websocket.onopen event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67009183/c-sharp-unity-ienumerator-not-working-in-eventhandler) to similar question I'm trying to enqueue my callback event inside the websocket.onopen event:

```
ws.OnOpen += (sender, args) =>
        {
            _actions.Enqueue(() => OnClientConnected());
            //OnClientConnected?.Invoke();
            //OnConnectionStateChange?.Invoke();
            //RequestValidation();
        };
```

however it doesn't seem to being added to my action list (`Debug.Log(_actions.Count);` inside my update always print `0`):

```
private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(_actions.Count);
        
        while (_actions.TryDequeue(out var action))
        {
            Debug.Log("is this even working?");
            action?.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

The whole purpose of this is so I can later start Coroutines (to for example repeatedly call send ping) from one of my events, which have to be started inside Unity main threads.

FULL CODE:

```
using UnityEngine;
using WebSocketSharp;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

public class UnityMultiNetworking : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region variables
    private static UnityMultiNetworking _instance;
    private WebSocket ws;
    public User userData { get; private set; }

    private bool IsConnected => ws != null && ws.ReadyState == WebSocketState.Open;

    public bool _autoReconnect = true;
    private bool _isReconnecting;
    public float ReconnectDelaySeconds = 10f;
    public int maxReconnectAttempt = 10;
    private int reconnectAttempt = 0;

    public string connectionURL { get; private set; }
    private  long pingTimestamp;
    public long latency = 0;
    private bool isConnectionReady = false;
    private bool isDisconnecting = false;

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    #endregion

    #region events

    public delegate void ServerMessageHandler(Message serverMessage);
    public event ServerMessageHandler OnCustomMessage;

    public delegate void ErrorHandler(ErrorEventArgs error);
    public event ErrorHandler OnClientError;

    public delegate void ConnectedHandler();
    public event ConnectedHandler OnClientConnected;

    public delegate void DisconnectedHandler();
    public event DisconnectedHandler OnClientDisconnected;

    public delegate void ConnectionStateHandler();
    public event ConnectionStateHandler OnConnectionStateChange;

    #endregion

    #region UnityMultiNetworking
    private UnityMultiNetworking()
    {

    }

    public static UnityMultiNetworking Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new UnityMultiNetworking();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
        private set { }
    }

    public static UnityMultiNetworking CreateInstance()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            GameObject obj = new GameObject("UnityNetworking");
            Instance = obj.AddComponent<UnityMultiNetworking>();
        }
        return Instance;
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (!isDisconnecting)
        {
            isDisconnecting = true;
            Disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        if (!isDisconnecting)
        {
            isDisconnecting = true;
            Disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(_actions.Count);
        
        while (_actions.TryDequeue(out var action))
        {
            Debug.Log("is this even working?");
            action?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region connection

    public void Connect(string url)
    {
        connectionURL = url;
        userData = new User();
        CreateConnection();
    }

    private void CreateConnection()
    {
        ws = new WebSocket(connectionURL);

        ws.OnOpen += (sender, args) =>
        {
            _actions.Enqueue(() => OnClientConnected());
            //OnClientConnected?.Invoke();
            OnConnectionStateChange?.Invoke();
            RequestValidation();
        };

        ws.OnMessage += (sender, message) =>
        {
            OnServerMessage(message.Data);
        };

        ws.OnError += (sender, error) =>
        {
            OnClientError?.Invoke(error);
            OnConnectionStateChange?.Invoke();
        };

        ws.OnClose += (sender, close) =>
        {
            isConnectionReady = false;
            OnClientDisconnected?.Invoke();
            OnConnectionStateChange?.Invoke();

            if (!_isReconnecting && close.Code != 1000)
            {
                if (_autoReconnect)
                {
                    _isReconnecting = true;
                    Reconnect();
                }
            }
        };

        ws.Connect();
    }

    private void Reconnect()
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying)
        {
            while (_isReconnecting && reconnectAttempt < maxReconnectAttempt && !IsConnected)
            {
                Debug.Log("Attempting to reconnect... " + (reconnectAttempt + 1) + "/" + maxReconnectAttempt);
                Connect(ws.Url.ToString());

                new WaitForSeconds(ReconnectDelaySeconds);
                reconnectAttempt++;
            }

            if (reconnectAttempt >= maxReconnectAttempt)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Reached max reconnect attempts: " + maxReconnectAttempt);
            }

            _isReconnecting = false;
            reconnectAttempt = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (ws != null && ws.ReadyState == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            ws.Close(1000, "Intentional disconnect");
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        Dispose();
    }

    #endregion

    #region client_actions
    public new void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("I want to send message: "+ IsConnected);
        if (IsConnected)
        {
            ws.Send(message);
        }
    }

    public WebSocketState getState()
    {
        return ws.ReadyState;
    }

    private void SendPing()
    {
        if (IsConnected)
        {
            Message pingMessage = new Message(MessageType.PING, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds().ToString());

            SendMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pingMessage));

            pingTimestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
        }
    }

    public void RequestValidation()
    {
        Debug.Log("Requesting validation from server");
        SendMessage("Requesting validation from server");
    }

    #endregion

    #region message_handlers

    private void OnServerMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            Message serverMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(message);
            switch (serverMessage.Type)
            {
                case MessageType.PONG:
                    HandlePong(serverMessage.Content);
                    break;
                case MessageType.CONNECT:
                    // handle connect message
                    break;
                case MessageType.DISCONNECT:
                    // handle disconnect message
                    break;
                case MessageType.USER_DATA_REQUEST:
                    // handle user data request message
                    break;
                case MessageType.USER_DATA_RESPONSE:
                    // handle user data response message
                    break;
                case MessageType.GAME_STATE:
                    // handle game state message
                    break;
                case MessageType.PLAYER_POSITION:
                    // handle player position message
                    break;
                case MessageType.PLAYER_ROTATION:
                    // handle player rotation message
                    break;
                case MessageType.PLAYER_SCALE:
                    // handle player scale message
                    break;
                case MessageType.SERVER_STATUS:
                    // handle server status message
                    break;
                case MessageType.CHAT_MESSAGE:
                    // handle chat message
                    break;
                case MessageType.SERVER_MESSAGE:
                    // handle server message
                    break;
                default:
                    if (MessageType.CUSTOM.Contains(serverMessage.Type))
                    {
                        OnCustomMessage?.Invoke(serverMessage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Unknown message type: " + serverMessage.Type);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Recevied message error: " + e.Message + " \nMessage from server: " + message);
        }
    }

    private void HandlePong(string serverMessage)
    {
        latency = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() - pingTimestamp;
    }

    private void HandleValidation(string serverMessage)
    {

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: FYI - `On*` methods are idiomatically the methods that raise the events, not the events themselves. So `OnClick` raises the `Click` event. Your naming convention is misleading.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ty for the tip. I'm still learning so I will keep that in mind and work on my naming convention later.

Comment: Have you debugged to see if your `ws.OnOpen` handler is even being called?  Maybe your connection is failing

Comment: @avariant yes. the `ws.onopen` is being called. `RequestValidation();` has both debug and sendmessage and both are working. the only thingnot working is `_actions.Enqueue(() => OnClientConnected());`

Comment: It's unlikely to be a solution, but it's probably a good idea to put a lock around you usage of `_actions`.  Because `ws.OnOpen` is called asynchronous to your update thread, there is a potential for race condition.  Adding a `lock(ws)` around your `Enqueue` and `TryDequeue` will prevent that.

Comment: Ah, wait.  I just saw that `_actions` is a ConcurrentQueue.  A lock should not be necessary in that case!